# Need advice on RegEx

Tags: regex

I'm banging my head with a problem but I can't manage to find a proper solution.
The problem:
Write a regular expression that will match all occurrences of a different chars or words in the text. The text order should be exactly this:

> pl play player

I've tried

> (pl|play|player)

but it will select only pl in all of the words for some reason. So does anyone know why is that and is it posible to do it using regular expression only?

Link to [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/6GuvK0/1)

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are looking for alternatives, start from the longest word to the shortest if they have/start with common characters. As `pl`, `play` and `player` all start with `pl`, only `pl` (as the first alternative) is matched. `play` and `player` are not considered.

Your regex should be :`(player|play|pl)`.

In this case, the words are tested/compared to `player` first, then with `play` if `player` was not found and then finally with `pl` if the other two words were not found.

Comment: Thank you. This is working. I'm just curious is there a better way to do this? I'm asking because if I want to make it dynamic I should rearenge words every time when I add a new one.

Comment: @nuik: you could use word boundaries `\b(pl|play|player)\b` [Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/IR6j6K/1)

Comment: @Toto said, add `\b` to match the words.

Comment: @nuik See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Thats great. Tha you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a greedy match, so add `.*` at the end of your regex, like so:
`(pl|play|player).*`

You have to be careful when using greedy matches, as you can end up matching more than you want.

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes, thank you. But if I aplied on a bigger text containing this words it will select everything afterwards. pl piere play player. It will find pl again and select the whole row.

Comment: Hence the need to be careful when using greedy matches.